# Can I put doctrine dbal and orm config in a vendor bundle?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, config, vendor

I'm just asking a question, that's can we put all doctrine (orm and dbal) configuration in the config.yml file which is localized inside a vendor bundle ? And how to access to this entity manager outside of this bundle ?

Thanks per advance

**EDIT1:**

I think it's possible by using the PrependExtensionInterface like that :

```
//vendor/XXXXBundle/DependencyInjection/XXXXExtension.php

class XXXXExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
     public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
     {
           $configuration = new Configuration();
           $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

           $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
           $loader->load('services.yml');
     }

     public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
     {
           $configFile = __DIR__ . '/../Resources/config/config.yml';

            $content = Yaml::parse(
                 file_get_contents($configFile)
            );

            $container->prependExtensionConfig('', $content);
     }
 }


# vendor/XXXXBundle/Resources/config/config.yml

imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }

doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default_conn
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%XXXXBundle.database_driver%"
                host:     "%XXXXBundle.database_host%"
                port:     "%XXXXBundle.database_port%"
                dbname:   "%XXXXBundle.database_name%"
                user:     "%XXXXBundle.database_user%"
                password: "%XXXXBundle.database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default_em
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        entity_managers:
            default_em:
                connection: default_conn
                mappings:
                    XXXXBundle:
                        type: annotation
                        is_bundle: false
                        dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/awcb/Aw/Common/Model/XXXXBundle/Entity
                        prefix: Aw\Common\Model\XXXXBundle\Entity
                        alias: XXXXBundle

# vendor/YYYYBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

services:
    common_business_profile:
        class: Aw\Common\Business\ProfileBundle\Lib\ProfileLibrary
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.default_em"] # already tried default_entity_manager and entity_manager
```

And I get the error :

> The service "common_business_profile" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.entity_manager".

You can note that a php app/console container:debug shows that there is no doctrine.* that's loaded...
Can you help me more please ? :)

Regards,

Comment: Cause I have a common bundle which will be in charge of getting all data from the database. So, the global Sf project doesn't need to be aware of any link with the db. I have seen that topic on Sf website http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html wich explains the ExtensionPrependInterface but I don't understand the principle and the coding phase.

Comment: Don't know how to fix this. I have the same error `The service "xxx" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.entity_manager"`. Can somebody please help...